# Speakers, headphone jack, and microphone are not working for Chuwi hi10x Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones

I don't have sound from my speakers or my headphone jack, and my mic doesn't work. I get Dummy Output. It looks like the system is using the audio drivers for the CPU which is the HDMI port. The speakers and headphone jack is coming from a realtek card. lspci doesn't show the audio card, so I'm not sure what to do. What can I do to fix this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two versions of this 2-in-1. One of them uses the N4000 processor (and sound should probably work). The other one uses the N4120 processor (and sound is not expected to work). Thank Chuwi for changing the hardware without changing the model name.

The N4120 model uses an Everest Semiconductor ES8336 codec chip for which support is only partial in Linux. Theoretically kernels from 5.19 should give you support for it. Unfortunately, I am finding out that the Chuwi Hi10X not only uses that codec chip, but it also uses it in some non-typical configuration, so sound remains broken. You can take a look at https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/2955 for progress.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I didn't do enough research before buying a tablet. I want a Linux tablet that can run desktop Linux apps.